# "Have got" and "Have"

Tags: have-got

Why exist "have got" if exist "have", while both this grammar constructions in most cases means the same thing. If I don't right, in what case we need use "have got" instead "have". [image]

Comment: There is no case in which you _need_ to use 'have got', though it is commonly used in everyday speech. There are many threads discussing this issue.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, "I have an iphone" is a simple statement about the present, while "I have got an iphone" is a statement about something that you did in the **past**, like saying "At some point in the past I got an iphone".  Consider "I have kicked the ball" or "I have eaten the cake".  "got" means "obtained" in this context.

However, this distinction is often ignored, so the two phrases have become somewhat interchangeable.  That site says that they mean the same: I don't think this is quite true, formally speaking, but from a pragmatic point of view they would tend to mean the same thing.  To me, "I have got an iphone" sounds slightly childish compared to "I have an iphone".

Comment: There is at least the one duplicate (as Kate had already implied); I've linked to one, and it has far more useful answers. In the UK, 'I have a phone' often sounds starchy, whereas 'I've got a phone' is the unmarked and colloquial version. 'I have got a phone' would be used for emphasis. Strictly speaking, ' 've got' is used far more often to mean 'have' than to mean 'have procured', so this is the primary sense. 'I've got a headache' is stative.

Comment: This is arguable in British Englishes, where *got* is the past participle of *get* and *have got* is employed syntactically as a sort of perfect. But it is not true in US Englishes, where the past participle of *get* is *gotten*.

Comment: @StoneyB I thought "gotten" was more of a colloquialism.

Comment: It's by no means universal, but by and large *gotten* is standard in US Englishes in all registers. My own touchstone for formal prose is Robert Caro's ongoing biography of Lyndon Johnson, and Caro consistently employs *gotten* for the past participle. ... What **is** colloquial is deletion of the *HAVE* form--"I got rhythm"--and the trend toward treating the resultant possessive *got* as an independent infinitive--"I don't got X", "Do they got X?".

Comment: 'Have got' is ungrammatical unless 'got' is a participle (which it is in BRE).  It often means just 'have' instead of 'have gotten', but the energy needed to say 'ha-' is greater than that for 'got', so we often say "-'ve got" instead of "have"; and we don't say things like "I've a phone" because the contraction is reserved for the auxiliary 'have', not the lexical verb 'have'.